# MS Teams App Development - Silent login to Azure AD using microsoft/teams-js

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I'm developing an app for MS Teams which a user can install for himself from the app store (Tab). I have a SPA with Angular 6 which I want to use to access SharePoint and MS Graph resources. The SPA runs as an App Service on Azure. In the team context, I have tried to authenticate the user to the AAD of a registered app via the MS Team JS. See code below:

```
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.getContext(function(context) {
      try {
        microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
          url: window.location.origin + '/assets/login.html',
          width: 600,
          height: 535,
          successCallback: function(result) {
            // Do something
          },
          failureCallback: function(reason) {
            // Say something
          }
        });
      } catch (err) {
        // Do other things
      }
```

This code works fine. But a login popup is shown when you use the app for the first time or log in again. In my opinion, it should be possible to use the current logged in user to authenticate himself to Azure without a login popup (SSO).

**Is there a solution where the app silently retrieves the accesstokens of both resources?**

[image: Current auth Process]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Silent authentication in Azure Active Directory (AAD) is a simplified form of single sign-on (SSO). Its purpose it to minimize the number of times a user needs to enter login credentials while using your app.
Please have a look at [Silent Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-silent-aad?view=msteams-client-js-latest) documentation.

Comment: Where did you add the client id of registered app in the code.. Can you please help me with more detailed code - kunalvalecha1@gmail.com